# Is it possible to realize the col floating point ratio in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Our Software UI designer give me a website image, tell me to write the html. I 
make brief description of his requirement:

[image]

he want the display like this, width ratio probably `5 : 3.5 : 3.5`.

I want to use bootstrap as the UI framework, and I am also newbie about the bootstrap. because the `col` do not have floating point radio, how can I archive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split'em up like this

Since your expected ratio is  `5:3.5:3.5` add the two least ratios  `3.5 + 3.5 = 7`

Now `5:7` `5 + 7 = 12` Since bootstrap grid systems has `12 grids` you can use `5 + 7` columns and split the `column 7` as two equivalent `col-sm-6`

So now the child `col-sm-6` has the width ratio of `3.5 + 3.5`

```css
.half-width > div{
            width:48%; 
            margin-right:2%;
            }
.half-width > div:last-child{
            margin:0;
            }
div{ 
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    color:#fff; 
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:50px;
    }
div .col-sm-7, div .col-xs-7{
    padding:0; 
    margin:0;
    }
div .col-sm-5, div .col-xs-5{
     padding-right:1%; 
     padding-top:0;
     }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="col-sm-5 col-xs-5">
<div style="height:150px; background:red;">1</div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7 half-width">
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="height:150px; background:red;">2
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="height:150px; background:red;">3
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested `row` when you using bootstrap like bellow to come true the column ratio:

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5">
                <div style="background-color: #eee; min-height: 100px;">5</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div style="background-color: #eee; min-height: 100px;">3.5</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div style="background-color: #eee; min-height: 100px;">3.5</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```